# Random Forest Feature Importances vs Correlation Matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to see the correlation between variables. So first, i used Correlation Matrix. It showed me the correlation between all variables. Then i create my `random forest regressor` model. In an article i found that it has function of `feature_importances_`. It tells the correlation between the independent variables and the dependent variable. So i tried it, then i saw that it shows the same correlation values with the values of Correlation Matrix. My question is, then what is the difference between Correlation Matrix and Random Forest Feature Importance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the code below.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Load boston housing dataset as an example
boston = load_boston()


X = boston["data"]
Y = boston["target"]
names = boston["feature_names"]
reg = RandomForestRegressor()
reg.fit(X, Y)
print("Features sorted by their score:")
print(sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), reg.feature_importances_), names), 
             reverse=True))


boston_pd = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
print(boston_pd.head())

boston_pd.columns = boston.feature_names
print(boston_pd.head())

# correlations
boston_pd.corr()
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
corrMatrix = boston_pd.corr()
sn.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
features = boston.feature_names
importances = reg.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)

plt.title('Feature Importances')
plt.barh(range(len(indices)), importances[indices], color='#8f63f4', align='center')
plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), features[indices])
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So, feature selection relies on correlation analysts to determine the best features we should use; which features (independent variables) have the most statistical influence on helping to determine the target variable (dependent variable). Correlation is a statistical term which refers to how close two variables are, in terms of having a linear relationship with each other. Feature selection is one of the first, and arguably one of the most important steps, when performing any machine learning task. A feature in a dataset, is a column of data. When working with any dataset, we have to understand which column (feature) is going to have a statistically significant impact on the output variable. If we add many irrelevant features into a model, it will just make the model worst (Garbage In Garbage Out). This is why we do feature selection.  Pearson's correlation (feature selection) is very popular for determining the relevance of all independent variables, relative to the target variable (dependent variable).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the scikit-learn random forest model, since it has that `feature_importances_` attribute. Though you might see similar results by checking the correlation between features and your target variable, `feature_importances_` uses a more sophisticated approach. From the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance-evaluation):

> The relative rank (i.e. depth) of a feature used as a decision node in
>   a tree can be used to assess the relative importance of that feature
>   with respect to the predictability of the target variable. Features
>   used at the top of the tree contribute to the final prediction
>   decision of a larger fraction of the input samples. The expected
>   fraction of the samples they contribute to can thus be used as an
>   estimate of the relative importance of the features. In scikit-learn,
>   the fraction of samples a feature contributes to is combined with the
>   decrease in impurity from splitting them to create a normalized
>   estimate of the predictive power of that feature.
>
> By averaging the estimates of predictive ability over several
>   randomized trees one can reduce the variance of such an estimate and
>   use it for feature selection. This is known as the mean decrease in
>   impurity, or MDI. Refer to [L2014] for more information on MDI and
>   feature importance evaluation with Random Forests.

The reference there was to *[Understanding Random Forests: From Theory to Practice](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7502.pdf)*. Of specific interest to you will be Chapter 6 (p. 135), "Understanding Variable Importances".